# I can´t show my search of an excel I have

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a python program that captures customers data and stores it in excel. I also made a search box so I can print the customer data I want but it doesn't do anything.

I´m using `tkinter` to show a window, but I can't show the search I did (the search is made in excel where the data is stored). This is the python code for the search.

```py
def search_csv():
    # Abrir archivo CSV
    with open('clientes.csv', "a") as csvfile:
        datos = csv.reader(csvfile)
        # Recorrer filas del archivo CSV
        for row in datos:
            if row == search_entry.get():
                result_label.config(text=row)
                return
    result_label.config(text="No se encontraron datos")
```

Comment: If you're just going to READ the file, then open it in `"r"` mode, not `"a"`.  `"a"` means you intend to write to it, and that will collide with the lock that Excel uses.  Also remember that you won't see any changes to the file unless you save it in Excel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems. The first is that you're opening the file in append mode. That means that the file pointer is set to the end of the file. Reading it will not return any results.

A second problem is that you're trying to compare a string (the result of calling `get` on the search entry) with a list (the result of reading the csv file row by row). Those two things will never be equal.

If you set the file mode to `"r"` (read) and modify your condition to something like `if search_entry.get() in row:` then your code will work.  Though, it would be better to call `get` just once and save the value in a variable, then use the variable in the condition.